# Webpack removes css from .jsx files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-modules

I have webpack file that looks like this (note - for now - I need to create both minified and not minified versions of assets - so this is not a mistake):

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const readSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "foo/bar/style.min.css"
});

    config = {
        entry: {
            "main": './main.js',
            "main.min": './main.js',
            "style.min": './style.scss'
        },
        watch: true,
        devtool: "source-map",
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist'),
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/i,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    options: {
                        presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                        minified: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss|css$/,
                    use: readSass.extract({
                        use: [{
                            loader: "css-loader", options: { minimize: true }
                        }, {
                            loader: "sass-loader"
                        }]
                    })
                }
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            readSass,
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                include: /\.min\.js$/
            })
        ],
    }

    module.exports = config;
```

Everything works as expected, but there's one thing that bugs me.

In a few of my .jsx files I have CSS modules being loaded from different third-party components, stuff like:

`import 'react-plugin/react-plugin.css';`

Of course my compiled js and css files do not contain these styles. They're lost on the way. All the css from style.scss are there, all the js from main.js and jsx included within it are there, but theses styles are not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is simply because you are using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` module. if you want to keep your sass in your bundle then modify your webpack config into this:

```javascript
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')


config = {
    entry: {
        "main": './main.js',
        "main.min": './main.js'
    },
    watch: true,
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/i,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                    minified: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss|css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        readSass,
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.min\.js$/
        })
    ],
}

module.exports = config;
```

and instal `sass-loader` and `style-loader` by this command: `npm install -D sass-loader style-loader`

EDIT: **I forgot to tell you,** you have to include your css or sass before your js entry point like this

```javascript
require('path/to/your/main.scss')

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

so that it is bundled together AND you don't have to include your css in the webpack config entry point anymore.

Comment: This way there are no styles at all, anywhere. There is only js bundles, but my css file is lost.

Comment: @Wordpressor please see my edit, sorry just got back from work so strill groggy :D

Answer (score 1):

Can you see what happens when you include `style-loader` too, like so:

`$ npm i -D style-loader`

```
//... webpack.config.js
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [{
    loader: "style-loader"
  }, {
    loader: "css-loader"
  }, {
    loader: "sass-loader"
  }],
  exclude: /node_modules/
},
```

Edit: remove the `exclude: /node_modules/` if you need to load files from there.

Then ensure you are importing it in your js entrypoint: `import "../css/main.scss";`

Answer (score 1):

The sass required not declare yet?it's possible to use ./sass/**/*.css/\ on your test to call any css style translate from sass.